# How to get the list of client related through the HasManyThrough relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-9

I have these 3 tables:

> **clients**

id - *integer*
name - *string*

> **projects**

id - *integer*
client_id - *integer*
name - *string*

> **tasks**

id - *integer*
project_id - *integer*
name - *string*

related through the *HasManyThrough* relationship.

In the client table I have a column relating to the number of tasks relating to the projects of that specific client.

I want that when I click on the number of tasks, I am redirected to the view of the client related tasks. While when I click it shows me all the tasks, but I want, as already specified, the tasks related to the projects of that specific client.

How can I solve this problem?

**VIEW:**

```
<tr>
    <th class="id">ID</th>
    <th class="">Name</th>
    <th class="">Task</th>
</tr>
@foreach ($clients as $client)
<tr>
    <td>{{ $client->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $client->name }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{route('task.index'}" class="link-primary">{{ 
      $client->tasks_count }}
        </a>
    </td>
@endforeach
```

**TaskController:**

```
public function index()
{
    $tasks = Task::all();
    //dd($tasks);
    return view('task.index', compact('tasks'));
}
```

Comment: You need to provide your `Client`, `Task`, `Project` model as well, to better assist you.

Comment: Also you forgot closing `row` in your example, this is probably typo, but verify.

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Models inserted

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco Please help me because I'm going crazy. I am new in Laravel

Comment: I would suggest to create a new route where you can parse the client id in the path and then use this client to retrieve relation tasks. If that make sense to you.

Comment: can you show me with a well done answer to understand well?

Comment: I updated my answer, try it now

Comment: Why is this IDENTICAL to sarah's question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73210615/obtain-the-tasks-of-all-projects-related-to-a-specific-client/73212536

Comment: We are two people working on the same project. I have to do one thing, she another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new route:

```
Route::get('/client/{client}/tasks', ['as' => 'client.tasks', 'uses' => 'ClientController@tasks'])->name('client.tasks');
```

Add something like this to your view:

```
//Not sure if that is a right syntax to bind the id in the route, need to verify 
<a href="{{ route('client.tasks', [$client->id]) }}" class="link-primary">
    {{ $client->tasks_count }}
</a>
```

Or:

```
//Route
Route::get('/client/{client}/tasks', [ClientController::class, 'tasks'])->name('client.tasks');

//and view
<a href="{{ URL::to('/client/' . $client->id . '/tasks') }}" class="link-primary">
     {{ $client->tasks_count }}
</a>
```

And controller:

```
public function tasks(Client $client)
{
    $tasks = $client->tasks;

    //return your view with tasks associated with this client
}
```

Comment: get Route [client.tasks] not defined.

Comment: @maurice create a `view` where you want to show the tasks of this client then.

Comment: I just updated a typo in my answer

Comment: Rename to URL i said this is a typo

Comment: Check my answer, you forgot backslash.

Comment: Here: `'/client/' . $client->id . '/tasks'`

Comment: @maurice  Did you get your question resolved?

Comment: App\Http\Controllers\ClientController::tasks does not exist.

Comment: @maurice Have you added this function to the Client controller? and have you added this route to the route file as well?

Comment: he apologizes, I had the wording wrong.  In the function I added the route to the view, ie return view('client.index', compact('tasks')); and i get Undefined variable $clients

Comment: @maurice I do not understand, did you get you result or not?

Comment: no because putting the return view('client.index', compact('tasks'));  i get Undefined variable $clients

Comment: yes yes everything ok, it works perfectly. I've been writing code for 16 hours. Thank you

Comment: Thank you, please do not forget to up vote my answer and hope you get it this awesome framework too.

Comment: already done, thanks for everything and especially for your patience

Comment: @maurice You are very welcome my friend.

Comment: in the view, the href could be written more easily?

Comment: @maurice Check the documentation and best practices. I guess yes

Answer (score 0):

As you have written

```
$tasks = Task::all();
```

All tasks!

You need to pass along the id of the client with the request, preferably with route model binding so that you get a client instance in the controller. Then you can load the tasks or the projects with tasks below them

```
public function index(Client $client)
{
    $tasks = $client->tasks()->get();
    //dd($tasks);
    return view('task.index', compact('tasks'));
}
```

or with projects

```
{
    $projects = $client->projects()->with('tasks')->get();
    
    return view('task.index', compact('projects'));
}
```

In this second example, you get a collection of projects with the tasks inside, so you can then show a list of projects and a list of tasks for that project